# grep: match everything except a word

Tags: regex, grep

I've found several questions regarding regex in general, but I can't seem to make this work.  I want to include within my pattern the *exclusion* of a particular string.  My use case is to find all lines in python files that define classes that have superclasses other than `object`.  So For instance:

```
class Class1(Superclass): #match
class Class2(othersuperclass, Superclass): #match
class Class3(object): #no match
```

I can use the following regex to match lines that define classes.  I'm sure it's not optimal but it's what I have and it works:

```
grep -n '^[[:space:]]*class[[:space:]][[:space:]]*[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]*[[:space:]]*(.*):' *
```

But I can't figure out how to exclude lines that have "object" inside the parens.

**Edit**: I should have been more clear.  I'm trying to search files recursively in my filesystem.  Currently I'm using `grep` from the command line, but if there's a better command line utility, I'm happy to hear it.

Comment: I usually use `grep -v` to exclude lines matching a pattern. So, for example, `grep ... | grep -v object`.

Comment: Why not use ast and os.walk?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham See Edit

Comment: You can do it all with python,  what is your end goal?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I know, but I don't want to.  I want to do it on the command line.

Comment: Edit your question so the sample input includes both cases that do and cases that don't match (otherwise a script that matches on `.*` will work) and provide the expected output given that input.

Comment: @EdMorton it already has both

Comment: Sorry, I mean MORE. For example, what would you want to happen with lines like `class object(othersuperclass, Superclass)` or `class Class2(otherobjectclass, Superclass)`, etc. Basically consider cases that would be hard for a tool to correctly handle and then provide THAT as the sample input/output, not just the trivial cases you already have.

Comment: @EdMorton Its all in the question. I want to match all classes that have superclasses, except when their superclass is `object`. The syntax it pretty simple. If its `class Class1(object):` don't match. If its `class Class1(anythingElse):` match.

Comment: So you want US to think up use cases for you to make sure whatever tool we propose covers those cases? OK, I personally don't have the time/energy to do that but maybe someone else will. Meanwhile, I posted an answer that'll work for your sample input. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you've told us about so far:

```
$ awk '/^[[:blank:]]*class[[:blank:]]+[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*[[:blank:]]*\(.*\):/ && !/\(.*object.*\)/' file
class Class1(Superclass): #match
class Class2(othersuperclass, Superclass): #match
```

but idk about other cases you haven't included in your sample input/output.